# function not executing on "pageinit" when clicked through anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Im trying to execute a jquery function on the app which uses jquery mobile

side menu is included separately

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
 <li><a href="test.html">Test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="test2.html">Test 2</a></li>

</ul>

</div>
```

Test 1 HTML

```
<div id="test1">
<p>This is a test page to check</div>

<script>
 $( document ).delegate("#test1", "pageinit", function() {
      alert('created by jQuery Mobile!');
    });
</script>
</div>
```

On the HTML pages i have the below java script code

```
$( document ).delegate("#test1", "pageinit", function() {
  alert('created by jQuery Mobile!');
});
```

When i click on the link, the `alert()` box is not being executed. But when i refresh the page then it shows the `alert` box

Can someone tell me why the alert box is not executed on the page if clicked on the link?

Note:

on the link if i set `data-ajax="false"` it works. I want to execute it without setting it to false

Comment: Please add HTML markup; two anchors don't tell much. Use `.on` and `pagecreate`.

Comment: @Omar i used `.on` and `pagecreate` but still nothing happens when i click. Works only when i refresh

Comment: This is not a correct page structure, please read more over jQuery-mobile. `delegate` is deprecated. Don't use alert for debugging. Your solution is simple, it just requires a bit of reading to understand how jQM works. `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#test1", function(){ console.log("test1 pagecreate"); });`.

Comment: @Omar you can see the live page here http://vidznet.com/tabupdated/test2.html (you need to click on the profile link from the menu)  i did try `$(document).on("pagecreate",` and still nothing happens when i click on the link. Its so odd

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the id of anchor tag that is causing the problem and bind function create a new function which is called by this object so when you refresh the page this points to that abject and shows alert rest see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: What do u mean by id of the anchor tag?

Comment: i mean by adding id to <a> tag